# SQL: How to sort by sum of fields where certain conditions are met?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a shop that sells items

Every time an item is sold, following data is placed in a database:

```
-item_id
-item_count
-bought_value (money spent to buy this item, taking amount into consideration)
```

Now I would like to know the percentage of money that has come in PER ITEM

I would like to have this information sorted but I'm not fully sure how to do this

What I currently have is:

to find total money that has come in: `SUM(boughtvalue)`

to find all items: `SELECT DISTINCT item_id`

iterate through all items and use: `SELECT SUM(boughtvalue) WHERE item_id = ...`

This gets me the results, but they're not sorted this way

What I'm looking for is something like "SELECT DISTINCT item_id ORDER BY SUM(boughtvalue)"

My PHP script that finds this information currently displays something like this:

```
15332-0.75640207175834%
18353-0.30683127676158%
18349-0.53882565675204%
18351-0.20954331095913%
```

All I need is to have this information sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `group by`:

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(boughtvalue)
FROM table t
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY SUM(boughtvalue) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select item_id, sum(item_count), sum(bought_value) from item_table group by item_id
```

assuming your table name is item_table

Answer (score 0):

Play around with something like this

```
SELECT item_id, 
    (
        SUM( boughtvalue ) /  ( SELECT SUM(boughtvalue) from tbl ) 
    ) as percentvalue 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY item_id 
ORDER BY percentvalue DESC;
```

Ususally I discourage subqueries, but I think the optimizer will optimize that away.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(bought_value) as bought_value FROM item_table GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY bought_value
```